# R: How to change significance level for lm()?

Tags: r, linear-model

I believe that the default is sig. level = 95%, how can I customize that? Say, 85%?
I read through the documentation but it didn't help much

Answer (score 3):

The lm() function in R does not just report whether or not your predictors are significant at alpha = 95%, but also reports the p-values. So you are the judge of whether something is significant or not - if you choose to reject the null hypothesis at all alpha<90%, you can still do this using the lm() function by printing the summary and picking predictors that have p<0.1.

If you want to change the ".", "*", "**" scheme, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283048/changing-significance-notation-in-r) is a nifty code to do that. Hope this helps!